# Get spesified column from result_array in codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I'm about using CodeIgniter for my first project. I have tried to get data from database.

```
$test = $this->komponen_model->get_participants_id()->result_array();
print_r($test)
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 ) 
   [1] => Array ( [id] => 4 ) 
   [2] => Array ( [id] => 7 ) 
)
```

And I got this. So, I need to call each element by:

```
foreach ($test as $ts){
   echo $ts['id'];
}
```

My question is, can I make the array shorten. Just like:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => 1  
   [1] => 4  
   [2] => 7  
)
```

I will be appreciated for anyone's advise.

Comment: you can use one more for loop & rebuild a new array the way you want. Else, you can also use Ralph's solution. Else, you can make some changes in your Object methods for returning response in your desire format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array_column`

```
$test = array_column($test,'id');

foreach ($test as $ts){
   echo $ts;
}
```